# Android collapseActionView does not show icon

Tags: android, android-appcompat

All I want is to have the Search MenuItem in my app show the icon and expand when clicked. Note that this is in a fragment using v7 appCompat version 20.+. I have a minSDKVersion of 14, target of 19, compile version of 19.

Here is my menu information.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.test.testapp.fragment.LibraryFragment">

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />

    <!-- Other menu items -->
</menu>
```

However, everytime I run the app I see the button show up as "SEARCH" (the text of the title) and not the icon! Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `icon` attribute should be prefixed with `android` instead of `app`, since it is not part of the support library.